# timing a function call as if-statement condition in cpp

Tags: c++, if-statement, timing, c++-chrono

I have a function and sometimes it gets called as a condition in if-statements, and I am interested to time exactly these calls.

I wonder if there is any way to do something like this for timing it in cpp:

```
using watch = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
std::chrono::nanoseconds time(0);
if ( auto start = watch::now(); SOME_FUNCTION(); auto end = watch::now();)
{...}else{...}
time += (end - start);
```

Comment: You could wrap `SOME_FUNCTION()` in another function, that does timing. That function could accept anything it needs of context as arguments.

Comment: @MagnusHoff can I write a psedu-function that takes any "function" as its argument in cpp?

Comment: Yes, using function pointers or lambdas (`std::function`). However, I was thinking you could write a one-off function for each case where you need to do the timing. That's a good idea unless you need to do this kind of timing all over the place.

Comment: @MagnusHoff in fact I need to it all over the place for many different functions. So instead of wrapping each function for timing, writing a simple generic function that takes two parameter (function, ID) and does the timing in itself is easier. I am still not sure how to do this generic form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that wraps the function you already have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using watch = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

template <class F>
auto measure_time(const F& f, std::chrono::nanoseconds& time) -> decltype(f()) {
    auto start = watch::now();
    auto return_value = f();
    auto end = watch::now();
    time += end - start;
    return return_value;
}
```

Simple exercise:

```
bool some_function() {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::chrono::nanoseconds time(0);

    if (measure_time(some_function, time)) {
        std::cout << "Yea\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Nay\n";
    }
}
```

You can also wrap a function that takes arguments. This is simple to do with a lambda expression:

```
void* some_other_function(void* v) {
    return v;
}

int main() {
    std::chrono::nanoseconds time(0);

    if (measure_time([]{ return some_other_function(0); }, time)) {
        std::cout << "Yea\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Nay\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is some fine detail about perfect forwarding of the return value of the inner function. `auto&&`? But I don't know how this exactly works. This implementation of `measure_time` (conceptually) copies the return value.